# Density of certain space in $L^\infty (\mathbb{R},\Sigma, \mu),$ for some finite positive measure $\mu.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a finite positive measure on $\mathbb{R}.$ Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\Sigma, \mu), $ where $\Sigma$ is the collection of all Borel sets.

Q:1) Is it true that the space of all compactly supported continuous functions dense in $L^\infty
(\mathbb{R},\Sigma, \mu)?$

2)Is it true that the space of all bounded continuous functions dense in $L^\infty
(\mathbb{R},\Sigma, \mu)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu $ and Lebesgue measure are mutually absolutely continuous. (For example, $\mu$ could be the standard  Gaussian measure).  If a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous functions converges in $L^{\infty} (\mu)$ then $\|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty} \to 0$. The $L^{\infty}$ norm of  a continuous function is same as the supremum norm. Hence $f_n$ converges uniformly and the limit is necessarily continuous. Hence the answer to both of your questions is NO. (Discontinuous functions cannot be approximated by continuous functions in $L^{\infty}$ norm).

[Suppose $h$ is continuous and $|h(x)| \leq M$ almost everywhere. Then $|h(x)| \leq M$ for every $x$. This is because the complement of  a set of measure $0$ is dense. If $h$ is continuous and $|h(x)| \leq M$ for all $x$ in dense set then the same hods for all $x$ by continuity].